# Kick off N Number of Asynchronous methods

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I currently have the code below - on my MVC controller I take car input from User and then call a service asynchronously passing in a package of Cars which have been uploaded by User which calls an External WebService to get info.:

```
const int packageSize = 100;
var packages = Split(cars, packageSize);

BackgroundTaskManager.Run(async () =>
{
    foreach (var package in packages)
    {
        await _myService.AddCars(package);
    }
});
```

So if my User uploads 560 for e.g cars my Split function will return 6 pacakages - 5 with 100 cars and 1 with 60.

Rather than having a foreach loop is there a simple way I can kick off n number of async methods where n is the number of packages returned from my split service but I would need to pass each individual package returned from Split function to the individual methods or is the Approach I have used above the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await Task.WhenAll(packages.Select(_myService.AddCars))
```

Comment: Hi - can you put a bit of info around this as too how this is working if possible?

Comment: Throws the following error unfortunately with code in place - The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1+HttpRequestChannel[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel], cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.